# as3 what is base and how to call base.scale

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I am following a tutorial from Adobe about detecting screen sizes. I am trying to best fit the screen to both IOS and Android devices.

Here is a great tutorial where I got the code: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html

However, when I use the term "base", as they suggest in this tutorial, I get the following error.
**1120: Access of undefined property base.**

Here is the code where I am getting the error:

```
// scale the entire interface 
base.scale = appScale;
// map stays at the top left and fills the whole screen 
base.map.x = 0;
```

Here is the code I am using in a function, minus the declaring of two vars in the package.

```
public function theScreen()
        {
            guiSize = new Rectangle(0,0,1024,600);
            deviceSize = new Rectangle(0,0,Math.max(stage.fullScreenWidth,stage.fullScreenHeight),Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth,stage.fullScreenHeight));
            W.text = "" + deviceSize.width + "";
            H.text = "" + deviceSize.height + "";

            var appScale:Number = 1;
            var appSize:Rectangle = guiSize.clone();
            var appLeftOffset:Number = 0;
            // if device is wider than GUI's aspect ratio, height determines scale 
            if ((deviceSize.width/deviceSize.height) > (guiSize.width/guiSize.height))
            {
                appScale = deviceSize.height / guiSize.height;
                appSize.width = deviceSize.width / appScale;
                appLeftOffset = Math.round((appSize.width - guiSize.width) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                appScale = deviceSize.width / guiSize.width;
                appSize.height = deviceSize.height / appScale;
                appLeftOffset = 0;
            }
            // scale the entire interface 
            base.scale = appScale;
            // map stays at the top left and fills the whole screen 
            base.map.x = 0;

        }
```

**How do I access the "base" class as Adobe is referring to?**

Comment: base is just "container" MovieClip's instance name in this case, as I guess all DispalyObject items are gathered in it. 
You just have not such a item on the stage (movieClip with the ibstance name - base), hance AS3 can't find it.

Comment: However, I don't see it in the adobe code so I was wondering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Flash CS3 require you to specify the base class when exporting for actionscript (as3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277073/why-does-flash-cs3-require-you-to-specify-the-base-class-when-exporting-for-acti)